# What are the pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

What is the difference between pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes ?

I don't think that there is no need of any code that is why I'm not sharing any code.

Comment: You could find this information with a quick search